# How to configure apt to access a deb repository over ssh?

Tags: apt, package-management, ssh, repository

I have a deb repository accessible with ssh (following instructions from [this site](http://sysphere.org/~anrxc/j/archives/2011/03/29/securing_debian_repositories/)). I use the ssh-public-key-based authentication to access the repository server.

How I can configure apt-get on clients to make it use a private key to connect to the repo? How to configure apt-get to use ssh-agent?

Whenever I call `sudo apt-get update` on a client machine, I need to provide a password for *vagrant* user. The source.list on the client machines:

```
deb ssh://vagrant@33.33.33.16:/ precise main
```

Update:

```
sudo ssh vagrant@33.33.33.16
```

Works after following [instructions](https://serverfault.com/questions/107187/sudo-su-username-while-keeping-ssh-key-forwarding/118932#118932) on making `sudo` work with ssh-agent. `sudo apt-get update` does not.

Answer (score 5):

Works. I have removed the user from the deb repository definition in *source.list*:

> deb ssh://33.33.33.16:/ precise main

and I specify the IdentityFile in /home/root/.ssh/config as suggested in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/184841/apt-sources-list-ssh-with-custom-port)